# What is unique in finance stock data?

Tags: finance, stock

I am building web app which display's stock data and user can rate particular company there, we are saving this ratings in our database and identifying if its already rated or not next time based on stock symbol, but we found that stock symbol might get change over time. so is there any parameter which stays unique like name,symbol or anything else which I can store in my database and identify if its already rated by our app users?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're free to add a Guid identifier to the stock, before persisting. Don't let the database storage add it for you. This identifier will make your applications be able to track what has already been computed, or not.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ISIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number) to identify securities.

Comment: Although [be warned](http://www.isin.org/education/): "We think of ISINs as immutable identifiers tied to a unique security, and that understanding is substantially correct. However, like all rules, there are exceptions – in this case, related to corporate actions. Corporate actions are status changes to a company or its securities. Sometimes, these status changes require that ISINs be amended or deleted."

Comment: Can I get ISIN number using yahoo finance API?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea regarding this?

Comment: There's the `yahoo.finance.isin` table, but I'm not sure if it's reliable enough to use in production.

Comment: This question might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519685/get-historic-prices-by-isin-from-yahoo-finance

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can use ISIN as Andrew Lygin said.

But in facts, it's hard to use it alone because not all data providers provides ISIN. You must often build a bridge between the stock format of data providers (often tickers) and isins.

Comment: Can I get ISIN number using yahoo finance API?